# React Native's NetInfo different behaviour on iOS and Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

I am using NetInfo from @react-native-community/netinfo
My UseEffect Code is:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const checkNet = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
        if(!state.isConnected){
            setShowModal("internet")
        }
        console.log("state at splash",state.isConnected);
    });
    return () => {
    checkNet();
    };
  }, []);
```

Then an Alert is shown to Reload the app and the following function is called

```
const reCheckNet = async() => {
    const data = await NetInfo.fetch();
    if(data.isConnected){
        NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
            if(state.isConnected){
                setShowModal("")
                RNRestart.Restart()
            }
            else
                setShowModal("internet")
        });
    }
  }
```

The pattern I am testing is: I turn off the wifi and open the app, it shows me the alert (which is good) but if I close the alert and turn on the wifi, the alert is only shown on iOS but not on Android. Please help in this